# Rebuilding expo bundle with a different slug

Tags: react-native, expo, publish, slug

I changed the name of a React Native/Expo app and wanted to change the slug to go with it, but got the error "CombinedError: [GraphQL] Experience with name '@-----/newName' does not exist". Using the old slug, it still works. Is there any way to rebuild the app with a different slug?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just had this same problem.

- Check your app.json and look for the field expo.extra.eas.projectId and delete it.
- Now try to run your build again, a new projectId will be generated.

This seems to have worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

**NEW UPDATE**

Goto app.json. Find slug name and  "extra": {
"eas": {
"projectId": your previous ID
}
},

Change to new slug name and also new project ID

You can find your NEW slug name and Project ID here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was creating a new project on Expo. You can go create one by clicking on All Projects ->

Make sure to match the slug of this new project to the one you specify in app.json and you should be good to go.